# Python3: writing article in own words

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, summarization

I am trying to extract the summary from news article. Here is what I have tried till now:

```
>>> from newspaper import Article
>>> url = 'http://abcnews.go.com/International/wireStory/north-korea-ready-deploy-mass-produce-missile-47552675'
>>> article = Article(url)
>>> article.download()
>>> article.parse()
>>> article.nlp()
>>> article.keywords
['ready', 'north', 'test', 'missiles', 'deploy', 'tested', 'korea', 'missile', 'launch', 'nuclear', 'capable', 'media', 'massproduce']
>>> article.summary
'North Korea says it\'s ready to deploy and start mass-producing a new medium-range missile capable of reaching Japan and major U.S. military bases there following a test launch it claims confirmed the missile\'s combat readiness and is an "answer" to U.S. President Donald Trump\'s policies.\nPyongyang\'s often-stated goal is to perfect a nuclear warhead that it can put on a missile capable of hitting Washington or other U.S. cities.\nAt the request of diplomats from the U.S., Japan and South Korea, a United Nations\' Security Council consultation on the missile test will take place Tuesday.\nNorth Korea a week earlier had successfully tested a new midrange missile — the Hwasong 12 — that it said could carry a heavy nuclear warhead.\nExperts said that rocket flew higher and for a longer time than any other missile previously tested by North Korea and represents another big advance toward a viable ICBM.'
```

I have seen that the summary generated in the above paragraph is taken exactly from the news article itself. Whereas I want to achieve human like summarization (In own words or spin content or anything, but should be relevant).

Kindly, advice me or suggest me the what I need to do so that my code works exactly what I want?

Comment: It's a hard task. I doubt that there's an off-the-shelf Python library that does what you want.

Comment: I second that, I flagged to question to be moved to ai.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is [sumy](https://github.com/miso-belica/sumy) which does offer several ways to summarize english texts. Most (if not all) of those algorithm will extract sentences from the input document. Based on those sentences you can postprocess them to split and/or merge sentences and use synonyms.

Outside that, this topic is still not much in the field of engineering but research. Try [AI StackExchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: but it doesn't gives the output in abstract or in my own words. It is more like extraction based summarization library.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the "custom words" thing. I updated the answer.